# 82GB of "other" don't appear in OmniDiskSweeper or Freediskspace

Tags: ssd, storage

I have a new MacBook Pro 13' where I installed a few programs and transferred my files from my previous MacBook. However, my SSD is already almost full, according to the settings (only 12.64GB left). However, when I try to see what takes so much space on my SSD with OmniDiskSweeper or FreeDiskSpace, I see only 140GB of files.

The roughly 80GB missing appear as "Other" in the storage settings of my Mac. Do you have any idea what is this data and how can I free up space on my computer?

I tried reindexing Spotlight as suggested in other threads but it didn't change anything. When I look at the free space on finder on my drive, I get the same number as in the storage part (only 12.64GB left).

Thank you in advance!

Edit: When running a scan with GrandPerspective, the volume of scanned files is 126GB but it also mentioned "miscellaneous used space" of 93.9GB.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Updating the mac solved the issue, the 82gb of data disappeared. Still not sure why it happened in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

The number Grand Perspective shows as "Miscellanous used space" represents the amount of data that Grand Perspective hasn't scanned.

This could be due to you only scanning part of the drive (for example just scanning the home directory for one user, whilst other user's data haven't been scanned), setting a filter or lack of permissions.

If you haven't done so already, I would suggest giving Grand Perspective `Full Disk Access` and try again. You do this from `System Preferences` > `Security & Privacy` > `Privacy`.

In case it is not due to files that are not scanned, the space could be taken up by file system snapshots - for example made by TimeMachine backups.

Answer (score 0):

My supposition is that these are probably APFS snapshots.

The best tool to use to see/delete these is [Carbon Copy Cloner](https://bombich.com/). Select the drive in the lower-left corner of the main window (see below where I have selected the drive named "SSD")

[image]

[OnyX](https://www.titanium-software.fr/en/onyx.html) can also do this, but my experience was that it would only delete snapshots created my Time Machine. Other apps can make them too. CCC can delete any of them.