# What is eating my disk space?

Tags: macos, mac, hard-drive

I have a 2020 MacBook Air with – theoretically – a 1TB solid-state drive.

The Finder says I have only 64.4G free; Storage in System Settings says 935.2G is used, 411.6 of which is "System Data". CleanMyMac similarly says 941.64G is used... BUT when I run its Space Lens, it finds 575.3G under Users, 74G under Applications, 12G under Library, *11*G under System, and less than 10G for everything else. That should be no more than 700G used - and it doesn't mention any "System Data". (GrandPerspective gives me a similar result.)

What is this "System Data" that's eating the remaining 200+ gigabytes of my hard drive, and how do I get rid of it? [This thread](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/404407/82gb-of-other-dont-appear-in-omnidisksweeper-or-freediskspace) suggested that updating your OS or turning on Full Disk Access in CleanMyMac could help solve it, but I did both and neither worked. CleanMyMac also didn't find any malware, even on a deep scan. I've heard it suggested that Time Machine backups can be the culprit for this sort of thing, but I have Time Machine set to back up to an external drive, as far as I can tell.

Performance has also been really slow in general lately (it'll often take several seconds to open a folder in the Finder when I click on it). I had a brand-new SSD put in in late 2021 (after a coffee spill); it doesn't seem likely that a drive would be giving up the ghost after less than two years. Something's clearly gone wrong here but I really can't tell what.

Comment: Have you run all these applications as your user or from sudo - some directories are not readable as a normal user

Comment: The user I run them as does have admin access, yeah.

Comment: You still need to run (in modern macOS) the app as root using sudo.